# jQuery, throw new error("Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "+e)

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I started coding before 4days ago.
I wanted make Webpage like to MBTI test site.
So I watched the paid lecture and copied it.
This error occurred even though we proceeded accordingly.
I'd appreciate it if you could help me. Plz

```js
function start() {
  $(".start").hide();
  $(".question").show();
}
$("#A").click(function() {
  var type = $("#type").val();
  var preValue = $("#" + type).val();
  console.log(preValue)
});
```

```html
<div class="progress mt-5">
  <div class="progress-bar " role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
<article class="question">
  <h2 class="text-center mt-5">문제 </h2>
  <input id="type" type="hidden" value="EI">
  <button id="A" type="button" class="btn btn-info mt-4" ;>선택하기</button>
  <button id="B" type="button" class="btn btn-info mt-4" ;>선택하기</button>
</article>

<input type="hidden" id="EI" value="0">
<input type="hidden" id="SN" value="0">
<input type="hidden" id="TF" value="0">
<input type="hidden" id="JP" value="0">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Please provide the complete code. Also the stack trace

Comment: Typo: You spelled value in `value="EI"` wrong. I fixed it in the snippet I made you. You can delete the question

Comment: @mplungjan 
very very thank you!!!! Can I erase the question or not? Can you tell me why I need to erase it?